# What is the difference between javascript obj.onclick and prototype's Event.observe(obj, 'click',fn)?

Tags: prototypejs

What is the difference between javascript obj.onclick and prototype's  Event.observe(obj, 'click',fn) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj.onclick is a [DOM0](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dom0.html) specification and probably has nothing to do with Prototype's `Event.observe` which is a wrapper around the DOM methods `document.addEventListener` (or `document.attachevent` for IE), equivalent to jQuery's `$(element).bind('click', fn);`

If you want to know more about the differences between DOM0-2 checkout this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).